# Could linking to search results on my page in an answer be considered as spam/self or product promoting?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising, self-promotion

For example in my related answers I'd like to link to my Vite or Vue answers like:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A14098260+vite

The problem is that Vite/Vue community support is bad and I suffered a lot trying to gain the knowledge and often an OP later seeks an answer that is already in my answers. My answers often cover advanced cases and I find them valuable for knowledge spreading/gaining. So yes I'd like to promote and support these 2 exact products. Though I wouldn't consider that spam. If I promote my JavaScript answers that would be spam imho.

So what's Stack Overflow's policy for such narrow cases?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Doing that would *actually* be promoting your answers. So, yes, that would be considered promotion/spam, which would be inappropriate.

If there are a *small* number of *specific answers* of yours, or someone else's, which are *directly* about what the question is asking about, then it would be reasonable to say something like "I [or User FooBar] provided a detailed explanation about [this very closely related thing] that you will almost certainly also need to know about, which you can find [here]". That would probably be OK, if you do it quite rarely and only when it's something *directly* associated with what's being asked about, but which isn't close enough to be an actual duplicate.

Comment: i thought also that a couple of related answers is ok

Answer (score 14):

If there's a specific post(s) that are strongly related and have good reason to be linked in a post of yours, link to those specific posts and give context for the link. If it's useful and relevant information, that should be fine.

But I don't understand how linking to a page of all your answers (which the reader then has to dig through to find relevant info- a list that will presumably continue to grow over time) would be useful. One of the points of this platform is to have little to no noise.